# Object in free fall & first order

Tags: calculus

An object is in free fall and can be modeled by assuming that the only forced at work are the gravitational force and air resistance. We have m*v'(t) = mg + f(v) where f(v) = -kv^2 and k>0. The question asks to find the solution of this separable equation assuming v(0) = 0 and 0 < v^2 < g/a. I'm stuck... I understand how to compute separable equations, but the v^2 is really throwing me off. I don't know where to start, please help!

Answer (score 0):

$\bf hint:$  without all the constants, this equation is of the form $$\frac{dv}{dt} = 1 - v^2$$ you separate this $$2dt =\frac{2dv}{1- v^2} = \frac{dx}{1-v} + \frac{dv}{1+v}$$ which integrates to $$2(t+C) = \ln\left( \frac{1+v}{1-v}\right) $$

Comment: what happens to the constants that you removed?